# С помощью какой функции можно получить ниже приведенный результат в Jquery?

Tags: jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ПРимер показан на картинке. Задачу надо решать с помощью jquery.

Comment: А в чем собственно задача то?

Comment: Сперва надо задать какойто значение в input а потом при нажатии на кнопку ОК он должен создать  столько же строк на верхнем часте страницы  сколько было задано изначально  @Anamnian

Comment: Автор, а вы знаете что такое Гугл? У вас видно что вам нужно, но то что вы пробовали написать не видно. Вопрос выглядит как ТЗ какое-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> С помощью какой функции

С помощью такой функции

```js
$("#add").click(function(){
   var c = $("#qnt").val();
   while(c--){
     $("<input>").appendTo("#input-container");
   }
});

$("#remove").click(function(){
   var c = $("#qnt").val();
   while(c--){
      $("#input-container input").last().remove();
   }
});
```

```css
#input-container { background-color: #f0f0f0; padding: 15px;}
#input-container input { display: block; margin: 4px; }
#options { margin-top: 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input-container">
</div>

<div id="options">
   <input id="qnt">
   <button id="add">OK</button> 
   <button id="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Извини Братан но твой код не работает @teran

Comment: @AkbarIlxambaev Что не работает в коде выше?

Comment: @AkbarIlxambaev давайте вы еще раз нажмете на кнопку "Выполнить код", введете цифру 2, нажмете ОК, и убедитесь, что два инпута, как вы желали, не появляются. А уже потом напишите ко мне обращения, без "ты" и "братанов", стиль общения дворовой гопоты, на данном ресурсе не ценят.

Comment: Прошу меня простить все правильно работает я забыл подключить библиотеку. А как сделать кнопку возврата(удаления ) @teran

Comment: @AkbarIlxambaev удаления чего? Всех инпутов, по одному сверху-вниз,  или каждого по отдельности своей кнопкой?

Comment: Например добавленные после нескольких уже существующих @teran

Comment: @AkbarIlxambaev дак поясните логику удаления. На что надо нажимать, и какие конкретно будут удаляться.

Comment: @teran надо задать количество инпутов

Comment: @AkbarIlxambaev дополнил ответ

Comment: благодарю вас за поддержку @teran